# Old sci fi cartoon - Yellow round spaceship and an alien crew on a planet and maybe a maze

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember this from when I was about 5 years old (1986) or earlier. I saw it on a VHS recording, recorded by my older brothers here in Sweden.

It had a spaceship that was yellow (maybe white) and round, the same shape as [the one in the MiB movie](https://meninblack.fandom.com/wiki/World_Expo_Observatory_Towers) with round windows that I think had red frames around them all the way around the ship.

[image]

I also think there was a crew, consisting of three or more characters, on the ship and a robot (or a mascot, maybe?) and they were on an alien base/planet that had something like a maze or something because they were chased around.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: You're not thinking of [Yellow Submarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Submarine_(film)), I assume...

Comment: No its not yellow submarine

Comment: This made me think of Fonz and the Happy Days Gang. Here is a link to a clip on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtW6wS3z97Q

Comment: Watched the clip and it wasent fonz either :(

Comment: It made me think of [Gilligan's Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilligan%27s_Planet). But from a glance, the spaceship from the intro doesn't match, the cast seems bigger than what you remember, and it doesn't look like there was a robot as a regular character in the series (though one apparently shows up in the first episode).

Comment: I dont think its this one but maybe useful to cross it off the list... Take a look at the Space Sentinels... spaceship is white and round, crew of three and a robot side kick... here is a link to a wikipedia entry. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Sentinels

Comment: Doesnt look like it is Gilligans Planet or Space sentinels... The agony of not figuring this one out haunts me...

Comment: I grew up with a cartoon, recorded VHS movie that fits your description. But I can not find it anywhere.
It was a yellow space robot called Pluck or Puck (in Swedish) that had three boxes on its stomach. And I think his ears was some sort of radio. The helpers were a boy and a girl who I think were from the earth, they dressed in blue vs. red clothes. They traveled in a yellow spaceship that you have drawn, Anehall. And I also remember the maze they run throw from the planet they landed on. But this is all I can remember.

Comment: THANK YOU FRIDA! You were right, it was Pluck.                   
          https://youtu.be/Ec4kHvK9Ra4                                                                                                  And so many old memories :)  Now to find it in swedish.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of [Ulysses: 2031](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_31), by any chance?

It's a retelling of the classic myth, and there is definitely one episode that has them meeting the Minotaur, who is in a maze that keeps changing its shape.

It's from 1981, so definitely early enough for you to have watched it.

Here is an image of the spaceship (credit goes to [Willman Ostorga on Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/391813236303187238/)):

[image]

And you can [see the crew on this page](https://www.behindthevoiceactors.com/tv-shows/Ulysses-31/) - this red character is a robot, who I remember being there for comedy purposes:

[image]

Comment: No its not that spaceship... Watched the trailer and it wasent ringing any bells either...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the OP identified the cartoon they were looking for in the comments section back in 2020, but until now, no one has posted a proper answer.

According to [said comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/191543/old-sci-fi-cartoon-yellow-round-spaceship-and-an-alien-crew-on-a-planet-and-ma/261777#comment657597_191543), the correct answer is ***[Pluk, naufragé de l'espace](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0271042/)*** (1979).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Orbit_the_Astrodog_and_the_Screechers_from_Outer_Space):

> *Little Orbit the Astrodog and the Screechers from Outer Space* (French: *Pluk, naufragé de l'espace*) is a 1979 French animated science fiction film directed by Jean Image. It is based on the 1972 TV series *Arago X-001*.
>
> The film is also known in English as *Pluk in Cosmos* and *Pluk in the Space*.

> Pluk, an extraterrestrial robot endowed with extraordinary strength, is stranded on Earth. He befriends the boy genius Niki, his girlfriend Babette and Niki's smart dog Jupiter. They all leave Earth in Niki's spacecraft l'Arago X-001, searching for Pluk's ship Le Cosmos. They stop on several planets before reaching Plukastre, the home planet of Pluk.

The yellow spaceship sketched within the question can be viewed around the 1:43 mark in the video below.